# Cannot re-import .csv file after transposing and exporting

Tags: r, csv, transpose

I'm working with a huge file to do some data analysis in R. This file is a .csv. I can import it just fine. However, after transposing all the rows and columns using `data.frame(t(data))`, I export it and cannot re-import this data.

This is the code I am using:

```
write.csv(transposed_data, file = "transposed_data.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

When I transpose the rows and columns, does something happen to the data that is causing these issues?  When using read.csv, the transposed data simply will not open.

Comment: What do you mean it “will not open”.  Can you provide the Read.csv code you are using?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @Dave2e After exporting and trying to reimport into RStudio using read.csv(), there are no error messages, it just keeps trying to load the data. I left it running for about an hour, but still, the data never actually loads.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, just saw the second question. The code I am using to import is `new_data <- read.csv(“transposed_data.csv”)`. I just saved the transposed data to my current working directory

Comment: A couple of things to try. 1. Set quote=TRUE in the write.csv statement, the lack of quotes maybe causing issues depending on your data. 2. Try using read_csv from the readr package, it is a little quicker and provides a status bar.